# What is the best way to format a string in Scala?

Tags: java, string, scala

I was wondering what the best way to format a string would be in Scala. I'm reimplementing the toString method for a class, and it's a rather long and complex string. I thought about using String.format but it seems to have problems with Scala. Is there a native Scala function for doing this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I was simply using it wrong. Correct usage is .format(parem1, parem2).

Comment: There is a thing in `RichString` which lets you do some nicer stuff here, though; whereas just using the Java API you do:

 String.format( "%s has %d bunnies", name, bunnyCount )

You can do the following:

  "%s has %d bunnies".format( name, bunnyCount )

Or even use it as an operator:

  "%s has %d bunnies" format ( name, bunnyCount )

Answer (score 3):

How about good old `java.text.MessageFormat`?

Answer (score 2):

The thing to watch out for with `String#format` is the fact that it is actually implemented using reflection (as of v2.7.4).  It delegates to the Java API, but the reflection adds a pretty significant overhead to a comparatively minor method call.  You may want to consider Java-style string concatenation, just for performance reasons.  As I understand it, Scala version 2.8.0 should resolve this problem.

Comment: The once comically overcomplicated format is now only:

  def format(args : Any*) : String =
    java.lang.String.format(self, args.toArray[Any].asInstanceOf[Array[AnyRef]]: _*)

Comment: Looking at the source of 2.9.1 this is fixed. `StringLike.format(args: *Any)` now simply wraps `java.lang.String.format`.